# Failed to set and update value in firebase after sign in with custom Token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to insert and update the value in Firebase after sign in with custom token but nothing happens in the database, where sign-in is worked correctly and `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference` is work correctly?

```
        auth?.signInWithCustomToken(MachlahDeliveryApplication.dataBaseAccessToken)!!.addOnCompleteListener{ it ->
            if (it.isSuccessful){
             val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
             val timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

             val locationHistoryMap = HashMap<String, Any>()

             locationHistoryMap["userId"]       = currentLocation.Id
             locationHistoryMap["latitude"]     = currentLocation.latitude
             locationHistoryMap["longitude"]    = currentLocation.longitude
             locationHistoryMap["IsTripDone"]   = currentLocation.IsTripDone


             database.child("Locations/${locations.Id}/$timeStamp").setValue(locations)
             .addOnSuccessListener {

                 Log.e("DataBase insert " , it.toString())

             }.addOnFailureListener{

                 Log.e("DataBase insert" , it.message)
             }

             database.child("CurrentLocation/${currentLocation.Id}").updateChildren(locationHistoryMap)
                     .addOnSuccessListener {

                         Log.e("DataBase update" , it.toString())

                     }.addOnFailureListener{

                         Log.e("DataBase update" , it.message)
                     }

         }


        }
```

Comment: Failed with some error?

Comment: I don't have any error but also no data inserted in database

Comment: Does this line `Log.e("DataBase update" , it.message)` return something?

Comment: no is't return anything!!

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener and log the error? What does it return?

Comment: Yes I try with it but it does not return anything and  it does not pass on addOnSuccessListener neither addOnFailureListener

Comment: Try to add a addOnCompleteListener . See what it prints.

Comment: it's don't pass on it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check out the firebase database rules to insert, update or delete data from the firebase.

here is the link you can check it out and if you didn't applied any rules just apply it. After that try again.https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

have you checked it that this query or path of database is correct or not?
if you not check it first using below reference code:

```
mDatabase.child("CurrentLocation").child(currentLocation.Id)
     .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          Map<String, Object> postValues = new HashMap<String,Object>();
      }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
       }
    );
```